# Same function in javascript and php, but different outputs

Tags: php, javascript, hash

I have this function in javascript - works properly

```
// javascript
    function myhash(str) {
      var hash = 0;
      if (str.length == 0) return hash;
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        oneChar = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + oneChar;
        hash &= hash;
      }
      return hash;
    }
```

And I'm trying to rewrite this function to PHP, but for same input gives different output than the one from JS.

```
// php
      function myhash($str) {
        $hash = 0;
        if (strlen($str) == 0) return $hash;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
          $oneChar = ord($str[$i]);
          $hash = (($hash << 5) - $hash) + $oneChar;
          $hash &= $hash;
        }
        return $hash;
      }
```

Inputs and outputs example:

```
console.log(myhash("example")); // output: -1322970774
echo myhash("example"); // output: 93166309738
```

Does anyone know, where could be the problem? They look same, but apparently they are not.

Comment: Can you give an example? Might help pin down the problem

Comment: @Ian Still, would be nice to know what's different. If I was in this situation, I'd just start putting `echo`s and whatnot all throughout the code, see where the discrepancy first appears

Comment: Don't forget to change the example to use myhash

Comment: @StephenTG That was my bad. I thought they literally copy/pasted the code and expected it to work. Then I re-read and saw the differences so I realized my comment wasn't exactly valid. I agree it would be nice to know the problem (the point of the question)

Comment: There are 2 good tools to show your problem - http://phpfiddle.org/ and http://jsfiddle.net which would allow us to test and help debug

Comment: Let me just say the culprit is on this line: `$hash = (($hash << 5) - $hash) + $oneChar;`

Comment: In JavaScript, on the 6th iteration using the string "example", the result of `$hash << 5` is a negative number (`96947249 << 5` -> `-1192655328`). I'm not sure why. In PHP, it's `3102311968`

Comment: My only guess is overflow.

Comment: @StephenTG Yeah, me too, but I'm confused because it's not near the max integer value.

Comment: And here's demos of each: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mga-i8b and http://jsfiddle.net/YJRA4/

Comment: @StephenTG That's a lie. I guess the max integer value is `2147483647`

Comment: it's overflow - JS constrains the `<<` operator to work on 32 bit _signed_ values.

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` operator in Javascript converts the numeric parameter into a 32-bit signed integer, rather than an IEEE 754 double.

To fix your PHP code, you will (at least) need to mask the result of the `<<` operation before you do anything else with it.

The code below produces the same result as the JS code for input of "example" using PHP 5.3.15 on (64-bit) MacOS X 10.8.4.  It may not work for other test cases, or on 32-bit versions of PHP:

```
function myhash($str) {
  $hash = 0;
  if (strlen($str) == 0) return $hash;
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $oneChar = ord($str[$i]);
    $tmp = ($hash << 5) & 0xffffffff;
    $hash = ($tmp - $hash) + $oneChar;
  }
  return $hash;
}
```

NB: the line `$hash &= $hash` is a no-op.  A number "anded" with itself will produce the same number.

Comment: Confirmed, it works even for another inputs I tested ... many thanks to all.

Comment: I feel like it *should* work on 32-bit versions of PHP because you're "constraining" it to 32 bits...aren't you? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your code

Comment: @Sylar I'm finding _some_ inconsistencies because my `&` operator is not correctly setting the sign bit.  It works better if you add an `& 0x7fffffff` to the final `return` (in both versions) to ensure that the result is unsigned.

Comment: So return part should be "return ($hash & 0x7fffffff)" ? But this "$tmp = ($hash << 5) & 0xffffffff;" must be still in code, am I right?

Comment: @Sylar yes, that's right.  This does of course change your existing JS hash code, too, though.

Answer (score 1):

[hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) is reserved function for php I tested with hash1 both providing same result

using test:

PHP result: 3556498

Javascript: 3556498

Comment: The real names of both functions are different than "hash", I wrote "hash" only for this purpose. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, on the 6th iteration using the string "example", the result of `$hash << 5` is a negative number (`96947249 << 5` -> `-1192655328`). In PHP, it's `3102311968`.

The problem is that in JavaScript, the `<<` operator causes the operands to internally be converted to signed 32-bit Integers. The maximum value of a signed 32-bit Integer is `2147483647`. The operation at that point in the loop crosses that threshold, causing an overflow.

In PHP, the max value seems to be the same (`2147483647`) in 32-bit systems, but much larger in 64-bit. `http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php` (near the bottom)

**DEMOS:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mga-i8b and http://jsfiddle.net/YJRA4/

Lots of information on bitwise operators and integers (hopefully explaining better what I'm saying): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: that is not the max value of an integer in JS.  It's the maximum value of a number that has been processed using bitwise operators.  If you stick to normal math operators you can do `96947249 * 32` and get the "correct" value.

Comment: @Alnitak The MDN docs say `The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers`. And then goes on to say `The numbers -2147483648 and 2147483647 are the minimum and the maximum integers representable throught a 32bit signed number.` You're referring to a `Number` with that operation, which is different. But your point is right; I'll update my answer

Comment: kinda - a `Number` can still accurately represent any integer up to 2^52.  The bitwise operators strip any bits beyond the first 32, but the resulting value is _still_ a `Number`.

Comment: @Alnitak I understood your point, I think I'm just beating around the bush - the point is about the operands being converted to signed 32-bit ints. Otherwise, `Number` operations can account for numbers up to `Number.MAX_VALUE`. Nice answer by the way with a fix :)